# sparql query sparql.query().convert() sometime throw exception while give output on Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I am running sparql query

```
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

    SELECT DISTINCT(?film_link) ?film_name ?wikipage
    WHERE {
    ?film_link rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
    ?film_link foaf:name ?film_name .
    ?film_link foaf:page ?wikipage .

    } LIMIT 10000 OFFSET  num
```

This query is running in for loop [0,9999,19999,29999,39999,49999]
sometimes results = sparql.query().convert()  throws an exceptions.
Some give results and some don't. While all queries are returning data when I ran these queries on  Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor... does any one have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Distinct.

When using Distinct query shortcut / optimization is limited and if you have many results your query could timeout (depending on server load)

You may look into this DBpedia thread for other alternatives / optimizations
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28653250

Also, distinct requires more server resources. Depending on the query it may have to evaluate all the results - even though you ask for a limit - and that could result in query timeouts (depending on current server load). 
I am not sure if this is the case for your query...

Comment: A very strange behavior, now when I ran same query, it started working.. is dbpedia sometimes undergo some maintenance at after regular interval of time?

Comment: Yes, you can check #dbpedia on twitter